# Appropriate data structure for a bunch of polygons

Tags: database

I'm not a GIS guy so this might be a very misguided question. At present I have compiled a python dictionary, on which I perform some simple processing and return some answers. My data is structured as a python dictionary right now:

```
entire_data = { "row1": {
                          "metadata1": "some info"
                          "metadata2": "some info"
                          "geometry": [(x1,y1),(x2,y2),...] #x,y are WGS84 coordinates
                        }
              }
```

The entire thing is a 100kb right now, but is expected to scale a lot more in the future. I plan to use this data (mostly) in the backend of a web application. Most of my toying around with the concept is done and now I need to somehow have it in a format for persistent storage. I looked into shapefiles but they appear like they might be overkill (also read some criticisms on the format). I can put them in a sql database, but the geometry field would have to be stored as varchar and that would mean a processing overhead each time an entry is to be fetched. What would be an appropriate format to put the aforementioned data into?

Comment: If you want to use a dictionary, there is already implementations in Python with the [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html)  format

Comment: Why would you store a geometry column as a CLOB when you could store it as a geometry?

Comment: Take a look at general Qs on _spatial databases_, eg, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44720/what-in-depth-spatial-database-systems-tutorials-exist and some _PostGIS_ Qs, eg, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3251/how-do-i-get-started-with-postgis  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10260/best-practices-for-postgis-production-environments  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6681/postgis-what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-geography-and-geometry-types